# how to change font family of Tabhost in android

Tags: android, fonts, styles, font-family

I want to change font family default to my font family.
it's possible?
please help me

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add font files(.ttf,.ttc,.otf etc ) in assets folder
set Fonts is to do it programatically:

```
TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/heartbre.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting font and so on:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/my_bolditalic.ttf");
                final TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                tv.setTypeface(tf);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_tab_selector));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "SomeFont.ttf");
```